# Agora RTC live roles

Tags: twilio, webrtc

I've been migrating a Twilio app to Agora and I noticed that there is no way to control who can claim to be a host of a channel.  What's stopping someone from putting a breakpoint in the line that creates the agora client and masquerading as a host? I would have hoped that the role would be baked into the token as opposed to based on scout's honour.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone how comes across this in the future, I finally discovered an answer.  The temp tokens generated on the agora dashboard allow a user to be both host and audience, but when you generate real tokens, you can embed within the token the role of that user:

https://github.com/AgoraIO/Tools/blob/12b7f1b63a6ab7d102f883516bf791dd718e13d3/DynamicKey/AgoraDynamicKey/nodejs/src/RtcTokenBuilder.js#L60

Comment: OMG you saved me some time mate! Thanks!

Comment: with the temp toke I was so confused how setting the roles on client seemed to have no effect